# javascript prototype change anchor color not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning prototype concept in javascript, here is a piece of code for practice intending to change all anchor to blue. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?

```
<script>
    function change() {}
    change.prototype.changeColor = function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.style.color = 'blue';
    }

    $('a').change();
</script>
```

Comment: Because the change in `change.prototype.changeColor` doesn't exist. You need to get the name for a link.

Comment: That's not how jQuery plugins are created. I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend (or prototype) `$.fn` like:

```
$.fn.change = function(){
    // jQuery way
    $(this).css("color", "blue");

    // Native way (no $() )
    this.style.color = "blue";
}

$("a").change();
```

Also you use a jQuery object to style the css. Than you should also use the jQuery methods for it.